# How can I fix RowNumberColumns in lightning:datatable?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable

I want to make header-fixed and rownumberColumn-fixed table in lightning:datatable.

Header is fixed by default, you know, but I can't fix rownumberColumns.

How can I activate CSS(like position: sticky) only for rownumberColumns?

Maybe there are some other solutions?

Here is my sample code.

CMP

```
    <aura:attribute name="mydata" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" description="初期化処理"/>
    <lightning:card>
    <lightning:datatable data="{!v.mydata}"
                     columns="{!v.mycolumns}"
                     keyField="Id"
                     showRowNumberColumn="true"/>
    </lightning:card>
```

JS

```
 doInit:function(component,event,helper){
        var sampleColumn = [];
        for(var i = 1; i<20 ;i++ ){    
            var sampleColumnItem = {label:i, fieldname:i,type:'text'};
            sampleColumn.push(sampleColumnItem);  
        }
        var sampleData = [{1:""}];
        component.set("v.mycolumns",sampleColumn);
        component.set("v.mydata", sampleData);
    }
```

CSS

```
.THIS {
}
.THIS tr td:first-child{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
}
```

This is screenshot when I try to set CSS, with `showRowNumberColumn="true"`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We dont have any control over Row number column. The only thing we can decide is whether to show column or not using `showRowNumberColumn` attribute.

---

However, below is the alternate solution:

Put this style in the component where you implement `lightning:datatable`:

STYLE:

```
.THIS tr td:first-child{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
}
```

This has to be added by opening `STYLE`:

[image]

COMPONENT:

```
<lightning:datatable data="{! v.mydata }"
                     columns="{! v.mycolumns }"
                     keyField="Id"
                     showRowNumberColumn="true"/>
```

**Important:** This is anti-pattern to reach and manipulate DOM of different component and most importantly different namespace component. Although this works in Aura, this will not work in LWC because of shadow DOM. So, this might break anytime in future when strict DOM isolation is introduced in Aura.

**With the data you are showing in question:**

[image]

Notice the row `1`. Its fixed

Comment: Thanks.
I tried your solution, and got blank rownumberColumn.
But it was not sticky when I scroll page.
You expected such a situation?

Comment: you need `showRowNumberColumn="true"` to get row numbers as shown in answer

Comment: you have to use CSS in Style component. Can you show how you implemented code?

Comment: I just added your style to "STYLE" in console(Style component mean this?).

Comment: added in answer. This style is same component where you implemented datatable

Comment: surely same component. Is this need some specify from CMP?

Comment: see answer. In COMPONENT, you should have datatable and in STYLE, this css

Comment: yes, I have datatable in my component, and opening 'style', added CSS.
The other CSS  are active.

Comment: if its still not working, you need to put code in question, or else i am not understanding what is the prob. Solution given in answer is working fine

Comment: added sample code in Question.

Comment: your code and screenshot dont match. You should ideally get records from database. However I added the screenshot, its working.